# The partial derivative of $\sum_{j=1}^n{\sum_{i=1}^n {a_{ij}x_i x_j}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can the partial derivative with respect to the $x_k$ of $\sum_{j=1}^n{\sum_{i=1}^n {a_{ij}x_i x_j}}$ be $\sum_{j=1}^n {a_{kj}x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n {a_{ik} x_i}$ ? What confuses me is that to me it seems like a special case when $j=i=k$ but the summations make it seem like there only are two different cases.

More specifically, when $j=i=k$, we have that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}a_{ij}x_i x_j = 2 a_{k,k} x_k$ and I cannot see how this is reflected in
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \sum_{j=1}^n{\sum_{i=1}^n {a_{ij}x_i x_j}} = \sum_{j=1}^n {a_{kj}x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n {a_{ik} x_i}
$$

Comment: One copy of $a_{k,k}x_{k}$ sits inside the first sum and the other copy sits inside the second sum.

Comment: Oh so is the final expression just a result of rewriting or?

Comment: Essentially yes. See Blue Pen's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply linearity of the derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}( x_i x_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}( x_i) x_j + x_i  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(x_j))  \\                   
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} (\delta^i_k x_j + x_i  \delta^j_k)= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} \delta^i_k x_j + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i  \delta^j_k= \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{kj}x_j + \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}x_i,$$

where $\delta^i_k$ is the dirac delta indicatrix, which is 1 when $i=k$,  and $0$ otherwise. Particularly, it appears $a_{kk} x_k$ in the first sumand and it also does in the second one, so you get $2 a_{kk} x_{k}$ plus other terms.